# Display time along with date in admin listing page

Tags: craft3, control-panel, admin

We need to display time along with the date in the admin listing pages. I do know that the tooltip will show the time. But the client needs the time to be displayed on the listing itself. Is there an option in craft CMS to enable this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output format for `DateTime` attributes is hard-coded in the `craft\base\Element` class, so there's no configuration you can use to change it. [See the source code here](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/3.7.30.1/src/base/Element.php#L3917-L3924) for details.

You can, however, use events to overwrite the HTML for any attribute you wish. You're gonna need to create a [custom module](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/module-guide.html) for this (don't worry, this is pretty straightforward). The event you're looking for is `craft\base\Element::EVENT_SET_TABLE_ATTRIBUTE_HTML`. You can find example code for event hooks [here](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/events.html#event-code-generator).

In this case, you're probably looking for the `postDate` attribute. Using the source code linked above as a starting point, here's a hook to modify the output format for the `postDate` attribute:

```php
use craft\base\Element;
use craft\events\SetElementTableAttributeHtmlEvent;
use craft\helpers\Html;
use craft\i18n\Locale;
use DateTime;
use yii\base\Event;

Event::on(
    Element::class,
    Element::EVENT_SET_TABLE_ATTRIBUTE_HTML,
    function (SetElementTableAttributeHtmlEvent $e) {
        $attribute = $e->attribute;

        // only modify the `postDate` attribute
        if ($attribute !== 'postDate') return;

        $value = $e->sender->{$attribute};
        if ($value instanceof DateTime) {
            $formatter = Craft::$app->getFormatter();
            $e->html = Html::tag('span', $formatter->asDatetime($value, Locale::LENGTH_LONG), [
                'title' => $formatter->asDatetime($value, Locale::LENGTH_FULL),
            ]);
        }
    }
);
```

You can find the available formats (`LENGTH_*` constants) [here](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/3.7.30.1/src/i18n/Locale.php#L185-L208). Of course, you can also use any custom format you like.

If you want this to apply to ALL attributes that have a `DateTime` value, leave out the condition that checks if the attribute name is `postDate`. If you want to only apply this hooks for a particular element type, attach it to the appropriate sub-class instead (for example, `craft\elements\Entry` instead of `craft\base\Element`).